# Property 'error' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-fullstack

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p><strong>Login Page</strong></p>
  
  <form ng-submit="formSubmit()" class="form">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="username" required=""/>
      </div> 

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required=""/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
        <span class="text-danger" style="color:red">{{error}}</span>
```

see this "errors" it is not working as it is said Property 'error' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z865V.png)

```
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, fix the markup in your question and also provide the code of your LoginComponent (.ts file).

Comment: Please paste the module definition

Answer (score 1):

It means you dont have a property called error in your ts file. I dont know what error needs to be but if you add:

```
error = '';
```

Its going to stop showing as an error.